What is the power series for $K_{\lambda}(w) = \int_{0}^{\infty}z^{\lambda-1}\exp\left\{-\frac{w}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)\right\}\mathrm{d}z$?
As the title says, I would like to know what is the power series for ( or at least a good approximation ):
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{K}_{\lambda}\left(w\right) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}z^{\lambda-1}\exp\left(-\frac{w}{2}\left[z + \frac{1}{z}\right]\right)\mathrm{d}z
\end{align*}
Any reference would be appreciated.

https://dlmf.nist.gov/10#PT3

Trying (immodestly) to simplify $NIST$ documentation to get rid of  the modified Bessel functions of the first kind
$$I_{\lambda}(w) = \int_{0}^{\infty}z^{\lambda-1}\exp\Bigg(-\frac{w}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)\Bigg)\,dz=2 K_{\lambda }(w)$$ where appears the modified Bessel function of the second kind.
Using $\large\color{red}{t=\frac w 2}$
$$I_{\lambda}(w) =t^\lambda \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\,\frac{\Gamma (-n-\lambda )}{\Gamma(n+1)}\,t^{2n}+$$ $$\frac 1{t^\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\,\frac{\Gamma (-n+\lambda )}{\Gamma(n+1)}\,t^{2n}$$
